# parse multilined json in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have a json file with large data like this:

```
 [{"pkg_id": 385 ,"pkg_name":" 10OZ NR 1/24      "},
  {"pkg_id": 822 ,"pkg_name":" 12OZ CN           "},
  {"pkg_id": 422 ,"pkg_name":" 12OZ CN 6/4       "}]
```

How do I get list of `pkg_id` in an array.

I understand if there was only one row, then I could do

```
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
NSArray* array = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"pkg_id"];
```

How to go about multiple lines. If I have to start a loop, how to enumerate the number of rows in dictionary?

Also tried.

```
 for (NSDictionary *status in jsonDict)
{
    [newArray addObject:[status objectForKey:@"pkg_id"]];
}
```

but `NSLog(@"%@", newArray);` outside loop gives null value.

Comment: The piece of JSON data you have shown is part of an array. You should show the whole structure so we can tell you how to get this array (you don't need to create it from scratch).

Comment: The whole thing is too big, just edited the question to give you better idea

Comment: looks like an array of dicts, so your code wont work.. check the class of jsonDict... I bet it is an array.

Comment: The JSON array is value of a certain key in the JSON dictionary. You need to find what is this key (or key path), and the object for this value will be a NSArray without need to "convert" it.

Comment: Isn't key supposed to be `pkg_id` and `pkg_name` in my case?

Comment: It's like an onion, all depends on what object you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given raw JSON, we can convert it to an NSDictionary or NSArray like this:

```
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
```

At this point, jsonDict will either be **nil**, an **NSArray**, or **NSDictionary**. You can iterate through the keys if it is a dictionary or the indices if it is an array.

Iterating through the keys of an **NSDictionary**:

```
for(id key in [jsonDict allKeys]) {
    ...
}
```

Iterating through the indices of an **NSArray**:

```
for(id element in jsonDict) {
    ...
}
```

In your case, you have an NSArray. If you want to get a list of all pkg_ids, then you can do:

```
NSMutableArray *pkg_ids = [NSMutableArray array];
for(NSDictionary *dictionary in jsonDict) {
    [pkg_ids addObject:[dictionary objectForKey@"pkg_id"]];
}
// Now pkg_ids = {385, 822, 422}
// Note, this is untested -- there may be minor tweaks but the idea stays the same.
```

Comment: If you say you're getting null when you print pkg_ids after the loop, can you NSLog(@"%@", dictionary); inside the loop and report the output?

Comment: This is listing all the values: `for (NSDictionary *status in jsonDict)
    {NSLog(@"%@ ", [status objectForKey:@"pkg_id"]);}`

Comment: Can you output the dictionary as well?

Comment: Wait, it worked. I had not allocated the array. noob mistake!.

Answer (score 1):

Using a fun little feature of NSArrays:

```
$ cat test.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(void)  {
    NSArray *ary = @[@{@"pkg_id": @385 ,@"pkg_name":@" 10OZ NR 1/24      "},
             @{@"pkg_id": @822 ,@"pkg_name":@" 12OZ CN           "},
             @{@"pkg_id": @422 ,@"pkg_name":@" 12OZ CN 6/4       "}];
    NSLog(@"%@", [ary valueForKeyPath:@"pkg_id"]);
}
$ clang -framework Foundation test.m
$ ./a.out
2013-05-20 17:27:45.798 a.out[2793:707] (
    385,
    822,
    422
)
$                                                                             0
```

---

From the actual string:

```
$ cat test.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSString *jsonString =  // Next line
@"[{\"pkg_id\": 385 ,\"pkg_name\":\" 10OZ NR 1/24      \"},"
 " {\"pkg_id\": 822 ,\"pkg_name\":\" 12OZ CN           \"},"
 " {\"pkg_id\": 422 ,\"pkg_name\":\" 12OZ CN 6/4       \"}]";

int main(void)  {
    NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@", [jsonArray valueForKeyPath:@"pkg_id"]);
}
$ clang -framework Foundation test.m
$ ./a.out
2013-05-20 18:30:34.346 a.out[2988:707] (
    385,
    822,
    422
)
$                                                                             0
```

Comment: I'm not able to add values to the array through that loop in my question.

Comment: You don't add values to anything with this solution. If the JSON in your question is the whole thing, your `jsonDict` will actually be an array, us it as `ary` in this. Otherwise, traverse the JSON to that point.

Comment: yupp, that got resolved. Thanks for the answer though. You just gave me something new to play with. ;-)